# How to Use GET after a POST with QNetworkRequest correctly

Tags: c++, qt, http, post, get

I have some problems for my code, I will try to explain best I can.

Well, I want to build a kind of bot to automate some task in a website (www.milanuncios.com).
I need to get source file once I'm logged in so I can save some references for my announces, so here comes the problem

I'm using QT, with C++ and QNetworkAccessManager.
I managed to download the source file from webpage www.milanuncios.com/mis-anuncios/ but as you can see this is a login form.

Once we log in, it refreshes and show announces, and I need to download file once it's logged in, either I don't get anything.

Well I tried to make a POST to the form as follow so I may be logged in:

```
   QUrl url("http://www.milanuncios.com/mis-anuncios/");
   QNetworkRequest request(url);
   request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

   QUrlQuery params;
   params.addQueryItem("email","htful1989@teleworm.us");
   params.addQueryItem("contra","4hwk");

   this->manager->post(request, params.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8());
   QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply * )));
```

Once I'm done, I use a GET to download the source, but it's always the same (The login form source, not the user area with the announces...)

```
      this->reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.milanuncios.com/mis-anuncios/")));

      QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply * )));
```

I have the following signal/slot:

```
void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) {


qDebug() << ("HolaREPLY");
qDebug() << "start test";
qDebug() <<  reply->readAll();
qDebug() << "end test";
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, maybe many things so I come to you for some light... Thanks in advance :)

PD: Form values for param query:

EDIT: Solution was given by mike, I wasn't calling GET in finished() SLOT, now it's working, but I'm getting another issue:

My form isn't being send good, I mean, I'm using "email" and "contra" as fields, but these doesn't have attribute name, just ID = email and ID = contra.

How can I select it?

I upload an image:  (Yellow are the fields I need, and red the one got by wrongly)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvJ8f.jpg

Comment: Are you really initiating the `GET` request after the `POST` (login) request has finished? the `GET` request has to be sent in the slot connected to `finished` signal from the first `POST` request. please post the code that is responsible for that. Or better, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that people can reproduce your issue, and you get more help.

Comment: Hello, I was calling it on bad moment as you imagined, already fixed it... Now I have another issue, it's about field names in the form. Actually they dont have "name" attribute, just "id" but it seems that the form isnt being filled correctly, i will update main post with details if you can help me :) thanks @Mike

Comment: given up this way. Dont mind on answering.Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. If you've found a solution to your problem, you should either share it (answer your own question) or delete the question as there is no longer a reason for its existence :)